# How can a +vly charged object conduct electricity?

Tags: electrostatics

How can a positively charged object conduct electricity, as there is no extra electrons to conduct electricity?

Comment: Are you speaking about a conductor? Could you please elaborate the question?

Comment: You should read about p-type semiconductor.

Comment: I read the title as "plus-velly charged...". Somebody, edit this :-)

Answer (score 2):

They can attract electrons. So they can initiate the flow of electrons by attracting them and thus, producing electricity.

I am not sure if this is the answer to your question. Add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Objects have sea of free electrons to conduct electricity

And also electron can jump from one atom to second atom and from that atom to next and in this way electron starts to flow in circular path and thus conduct electricity

Answer (score 0):

1. Positively charged ions can conduct electricity when they move in solution.
2. Electrons don't have to be "extra" to contribute to conduction. For example in a metal wire, the wire can be electrically neutral and still conductive. A slight deficit of electrons, producing a positively charged wire, would not change this.